# How do T & F work as abbreviations for TRUE & FALSE in R?

Tags: r, specifications

T and F are not reserved keywords in R while TRUE and FALSE are.  However, T and F can still be used in many places as abbreviations of TRUE and FALSE.

I can't find any reference to this in the R language specification; maybe I am missing something:

https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.pdf

I know that using the abbreviations can result in some fatally incorrect results if either T or F were overwritten:

```r
T <- FALSE
print(T)
print(F)
```

So I am wondering what mechanism allows the use of T and F as abbreviations?
Why was this ever allowed in the first place?

EDITED EXTRA NOTE:

Immediately after writing this question I continued work in R and found how dangerous it was to use the abbreviations rather than the full booleans TRUE & FALSE.  Because I had tested the code above in my RStudio console T was overwritten to FALSE in my environment; when I started to run some scripts everything started to go wrong because until today I'd always used the abbreviations & of course T was now behaving as FALSE.

It took me 5 minutes to figure out what was going wrong but could have taken a lot longer if I wasn't already aware of this issue & it wasn't already recently in mind.

So don't use the abbreviations! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are objects in the `base` namespace.

```
find("T")
[1] "package:base"
find("F")
[1] "package:base"
```

Technically, you don't overwrite them, you create objects in an environment that has higher precedence in the search path that mask these (most likely the global environment), but you can still access them directly.

```
T <- FALSE
T
[1] FALSE
base::T
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a statement about this in the docs for logical vectors https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/logical.html:

```
"TRUE and FALSE are reserved words denoting logical constants in the R language, whereas T and F are global variables whose initial values set to these. All four are logical(1) vectors."
```

So T and F are variables in the global environment. But you could reasonably redefine those variables.

Although they provide a useful short hand for interactive use, I'd try to avoid using them in packages / scripts.

Answer (score 1):

From `?logical`

> TRUE and FALSE are reserved words denoting logical constants in the R language, whereas T and F are global variables whose initial values set to these. All four are logical(1) vectors.

So `T` and `F` are initially set to `TRUE` and `FALSE` respectively which can be later changed.

so `T <- 0` works but not `TRUE <- 0`